# Sequelize TypeError build.save is not a function

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I have some jQuery logic setup where users can submit multiple field values, which should be created as individual records in my database. My former solution to doing this was to map my values to a variable that is then used with the `.bulkCreate` method, but I was unaware that MYSQL does not support auto-incrementing fields with this method. As a result I decided to take my logic and instead create a for loop with the `.create` method. Unfortunately I receive this error message: `TypeError: this.build(...).save is not a function` at the line `models.DiscoverySource.create(sources)`. Why does this message appear when I'm not using the build method?

```
.post(function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.discoverySource);
    var sources = _.map(req.body.discoverySource, function (source) {
        return {
             discoverySource: source,
             organizationId: req.body.organizationId
        };
    });
    console.log("These are the" + sources); //outputs "These are the [object Object],[object Object], [object Object]
    console.log(sources[0].discoverySource); //outputs correctly first value 
    console.log(sources[0].organizationId); //outputs correctly the first value

    for (i=0; i < sources.length; i++){
        models.DiscoverySource.create(sources)
        .then(function(){
        return models.DiscoverySource.findAll();
        }).then(function(discoverySource){
        console.log(discoverySource);
        res.redirect('/app');
        }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
        console.log('Error during Post: ' + error);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `create` method cannot accept an array of objects.
If you need the ID's, and need to wait until all the object are created, you will need to wait for all the individual `create` promises :

```
var promises = sources.map(source => models.DiscoverySource.create(source));

Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => models.DiscoverySource.findAll())
.then(discoverySource => {
  console.log(discoverySource);
  res.redirect('/app');
}).catch(error => {
  res.send(error);
  console.log('Error during Post: ' + error);
});
```